# How to execute a a remote script in a reusable github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I have this workflow in a repo called `terraform-do-database` and I'm trying to use a reusable workflow coming from the public repo `foo/git-workflows/.github/workflows/tag_validation.yaml@master`

```
name: Tag Validation

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
  push:
    branches:    
      - '*'         # matches every branch that doesn't contain a '/'
      - '*/*'       # matches every branch containing a single '/'
      - '**'        # matches every branch
      - '!master'   # excludes master
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  tag_check:
    uses: foo/git-workflows/.github/workflows/tag_validation.yaml@master
```

And this is the reusable workflow file from the public `git-workflows` repo that has the script that should run on it. What is happening is that the workflow is trying to use a script inside the repo `terraform-do-database`

```
name: Tag Validation

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
  workflow_call:

jobs:

  tag_check:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Verify the tag value
        run: ./scripts/tag_verify.sh
```

So the question: How can I make the workflow use the script stored in the `git-worflows` repo instead of the terraform-do-database?

I want to have a single repo where I can call the workflow and the scripts, I don't want to have everything duplicated inside all my repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it adding a few more commands to manually download the script and execute it.

```
steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Check current directory
        run: pwd
      - name: Download the script
        run: curl -o $PWD/tag_verify.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foo/git-workflows/master/scripts/tag_verify.sh
      - name: Give script permissions
        run: chmod +x $PWD/tag_verify.sh
      - name: Execute script
        run: $PWD/tag_verify.sh
```

Answer (score 8):

One way to go about this is perform a checkout inside your reusable workflow that essentially clones the content of the repo where your scripts are and only then you can access it. It's not the cleanest solution but it works.

Perform a second checkout, to clone your repo that has the reusable workflow into a dir `reusable-workflow-repo`

```
- name: Checkout reusable workflow dir
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: <your-org>/terraform-do-database
    token: ${{ secrets.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
    path: reusable-workflow-repo
```

Now you have all the code you need inside `reusable-workflow-repo`. Use `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}` to find the current path and simply append the path to the script.

```
- name: Verify the tag value
  run: ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/reusable-workflow-repo/scripts/tag_verify.sh
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I wonder how we can know REF used to call reusable workflow, for example: `uses: author/repository/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@dev`. Here we want to use the workflow from branch `dev` but inside the workflow I didn't find any information about this.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if I wrap the script into a composite action. I can use GitHub context `github.action_path` to locate the scripts.
Example:

`run: ${{ github.action_path }}/scripts/foo.sh`

Comment: Are you sure this works? AFAIK, the `github` context is always associated with the _calling_ workflow ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#:~:text=When%20a%20reusable%20workflow%20is%20triggered%20by%20a%20caller%20workflow%2C%20the%20github%20context%20is%20always%20associated%20with%20the%20caller%20workflow.)), but the OP asks to access other files from the _called_ (reusable) workflow.

Comment: @PhilippBammes that is why I said, "if I warp the script into a composite action". This extra layer "action" allows you to access the script.

Answer (score 1):

Following Kaleby Cadorin example but for the case where the script is in a private repository

```
- name: Download & run script
        run: |          
          curl --header "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.MY_PAT }}" \
            --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.raw' \
            --remote-name \
            --location https://raw.githubusercontent.com/COMPANY/REPO/BRANCH/PATH/script.sh
                
          chmod +x script.sh
          ./script.sh
```

Note: `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't seem to work here, a `PAT` is required.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread on github-community](https://github.community/t/issue-running-shell-command-in-reusable-workflow/243982/4) the script needs to be downloaded/checked out separatly.

The "reusable" workflow you posted is not reusable in this sense, because since it is not downloading the script the workflow can only run within its own repository (or a repository that already has the script).

Comment: Hey @SebDieBln how can I download the script separately?

Comment: @KalebyCadorin This [thread on github-community](https://github.community/t/download-remote-file-in-github-actions/175417) points out some ways to download a file.